# Daemonize Log.io in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd

Ok, systemd is new to me.

I use log.io to monitor some logs.  In older distros, I could daemonize like this https://github.com/NarrativeScience/Log.io/wiki/Daemonizing-log.io-on-Ubuntu-using-upstart-(v0.3.x)

Now, it is done differently.  Anyone have a unit file for log.io?

Answer (score 0):

It will be something along these lines.  You might have to tweak this, as I don't use log.io.

Ideally, the server program would be capable of receiving its listening sockets as already-open file descriptors.  That would make it easier to use with several service management systems.  It does not, however.  Hence the tricky ordering and dependencies.  This is something that you might want to take up with the authors of the program.

```
# log.io-server.service

[Unit]
Description=log.io server
Documentation=http://askubuntu.com/a/822099/43344
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
# Some people use "logio" as the name of the dedicated user account.
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/log.io-server

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
# log.io-harvester.service

[Unit]
Description=log.io harvester
Documentation=http://askubuntu.com/a/822099/43344
# This is because the server's socket is not opened early.
After=log.io-server.service
# Starting this will auto-start the server as well.
Wants=log.io-server.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
# Some people use "logio" as the name of the dedicated user account.
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/log.io-harvester

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```